# How to fix this "New tab" issue in Chromium?

Tags: 11.04, unity, chromium

When I open a new tab in chromium it switches to another open window in **the same workspace only!.**

And it happens using (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), the plus icon, or any other opened 
tab.

**What I've done recently:**

- I've edited `chromium.deskop` in `~/.local/share/applications` , to make a static quick-lists.
- I've added  the daily PPA for Chromium (maybe because it is in development ?) .
- **Chromium version:** `Chromium 14.0.808.0 Ubuntu 11.04`.
- I've fully removed Chromium and installed it again, but it didn't work.
- I didn't touch `ccsm`, only the Unity Plugin.

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: For users having this similar problem , it is a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/804799). and here is a [workaround](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=88124).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a workaround:

http://www.mail-archive.com/linux-traipu@lists.launchpad.net/msg00886.html

Bye

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was fixed in the daily build a few days ago.